# Regex match everything after question mark?

Tags: regex

I have a feed in Yahoo Pipes and want to match everything after a question mark.

So far I've figured out how to match the question mark using..

```
\?
```

Now just to match everything that is after/follows the question mark.

Comment: `\?.*` matches everything (including an empty string) after `?`.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: For those using Java, it's `"\\?"`

Answer (score 367):

```
\?(.*)
```

You want the content of the first capture group.

Comment: @Dreamonic Don't think it's happening :(

Comment: @Starkers You right. It won't happen. Mark hasn't been on since `Feb 5 '11 at 10:41`. It is still good to point out every change we get. Maybe someone will learn from Dreamonic pointing this out.

Comment: how would you capture the content after the last question mark? i want to 'anchor' from thereafter - im not sure if anchor is the right word.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon first capture group in ^.*\?([^?]*)$ should work

Comment: Hello from 10 years in the future :). This answer matches everything after the question mark but includes the question mark. How can I remove the question mark from the match?

Comment: What about if I want to capture multiple lines after the question mark?

Comment: @Matthew, try `(?<=\?).*` this will only match everything after `?`

Answer (score 109):

Try this:

```
\?(.*)
```

The parentheses are a capturing group that you can use to extract the part of the string you are interested in.

If the string can contain new lines you may have to use the "dot all" modifier to allow the dot to match the new line character. Whether or not you have to do this, and how to do this, depends on the language you are using. It appears that you forgot to mention the programming language you are using in your question.

Another alternative that you can use if your language supports fixed width lookbehind assertions is:

```
(?<=\?).*
```

Comment: Oh the fixed width? Can I do a look behind for something like this?

Topics: code, programming, design

So I want to select the colon and look behind as far as the cpaital T of topics and fowards to the end on the line? (in this case end of the line is "design".

Comment: @Mark: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using Yahoo Pipes which excepts regex. I got this question answered and now looking for a regex that select 6 chars behind a colon and as many (all) forwards..

Comment: @Mark: I checked your list of questions but I don't see your new one. Are you sure you have posted it?

Comment: I will ask this new question again in a few moments. Guess it's best to keep my questions separate and really should have asked both at the same time. Thanks

Answer (score 59):

With the *positive lookbehind* technique:

`(?<=\?).*`

*(We're searching for a text preceded by a question mark here)*

```
Input: derpderp?mystring blahbeh
Output: mystring blahbeh
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/Ti8siS/1)

Basically the `?<=` is a group construct, that **requires** the escaped question-mark, before any match can be made.

They perform really well, but not all implementations support them.

Comment: not working on safari

Comment: this is the solution to the question. Requested was AFTER "?" nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

```
\?(.*)$
```

If you want to match all chars after "?" you can use a group to match any char, and you'd better use the "$" sign to indicate the end of line.

Comment: In most regular expression implementations the `.` by default doesn't match the new line character. As a result, even without the end of line character in the expression it would match up to the end of the line.

Answer (score 11):

?(.*\n)+

With this you can get everything Even a new line

Comment: If you don't care about new line, remove \n from this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this site: http://rubular.com/ Basically the site allows you to enter some example text (what you would be looking for on your site) and then as you build the regular expression it will highlight what is being matched in real time.

Comment: Thanks for that, do you know how to match a colon? And a certain amount of characters before the colon?

Comment: `/([a-zA-Z]{4}):/` will match `Test: Welcome` and grab `Test`

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace(/^.+?\"|^.|\".+/, '');`

This is sometimes bad to use when you wanna select what else to remove between "" and you cannot use it more than twice in one string. All it does is select whatever is not in between "" and replace it with nothing.

Even for me it is a bit confusing, but ill try to explain it. `^.+?` (not anything OPTIONAL) till first `"` then `|` Or/stop (still researching what it really means) till/at `^.` has selected nothing until before the 2nd `"` using (`|` stop/at). And select all that comes after with .+.

Comment: Please consider adding a description of your code so we know what it does and why.