# javascript Replace entire line from certain word

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replace all the character after certain word using javascript replace method.

For example: "This is sample text."

When ever line contain "sample" then from word "sample" to end of line should replace with "***".
The line should be

"The is ***"

I know that i have to use regular expression but what should be it i dont know?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419000/regex-match-everything-after-qauestion-mark

Comment: But line do you mean the horizontal line (i.e. till character.top remains the same) OR do you mean the sentence?

Comment: `text.replace(/sample.*$/, '*')`

Comment: thanks elclanrs you solve my problem.Can you any give me any link from where i can improve my javascript and regular expression.

Comment: @MethewSolis I think my code is working perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use this

```
<div id="something">this is sample value</div>


var value=$('div:contains("sample")').text();

var newvalue=value.substr(0,value.search( 'sample' ))
```