# How to select element has class start and end with specific string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, class-attributes, jquery

I got several divs using classes like

- .wrap-1-addon-1
- .wrap-2-addon-1
- .wrap-3-addon-1

I want to select all of them and use `if ( $(this).hasClass() )` to check if its one of them. Currently I only do check for a single class. How can I check all of these, for example `.hasClass('wrap-*-addon-1')`?

Best regards.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes).

Comment: If you want to avoid serious performance issues then you might consider applying classes to your elements like this `<div class="wrap wrap-1-addon-1"></div><div class="wrap wrap-2-addon-1"></div>` and simply target the `wrap`. Not sure how many of these are possible in your system but wildcards and regex will make your app sluggish at some point and hardcoding every possible combination would be insanity.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks for the suggestion. Sadly the code is generated by a third party plugin which offers limited possibilities to customize code without loosing future updates compatibility.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can combine two jquery [Attribute Starts With Selector `[name^=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [Attribute Ends With Selector `[name$=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to do this work.

```
$('div[class^="wrap-"][class$="-addon-1"]')
```

```js
$('div[class^="wrap-"][class$="-addon-1"]').css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-1-addon-1">wrap-1-addon-1</div>
<div class="wrap-2-addon-1">wrap-2-addon-1</div>
<div class="wrap-3-addon-1">wrap-3-addon-1</div>
<div class="wrap-3-addon-2">wrap-3-addon-2</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to adopt your answer using `.hasClass` or `.is` as questioned, but it does not work. Do you got a suggestion why? http://jsbin.com/qomubezoti/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: This won't work if there are other classes on the element as the `class` attribute won't start and end as expected: `<div class="foo wrap-1-addon-1"> <div class="wrap-1-addon-1 bar">`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('div[class^="wrap"]')
```

[JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dbjqzeoL/)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `.is()` which support multiple classes, unfortunately `.hasClass()` works only for one class at a time.

Example:

```
element.is('.wrap-1-addon-1, .wrap-2-addon-1, .wrap-2-addon-1')
```

Answer (score 3):

It is better to add another class and select with this class. You can then test it with regex.

```js
$el = $(".wrap");

$el.each(function() {
  var test = /wrap-[1-3]-addon-1/.test($(this).attr("class"));
  $(".result").html(test);
  console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-1-addon-1 wrap"></div>
<div class="wrap-2-addon-1 wrap"></div>
<div class="wrap-3-addon-1 wrap"></div>
  
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: This will only selects `.wrap-3-addon-1` elements. (no `.wrap-2-addon-1`, no `.wrap-2-addon-1`)

Comment: This is only an example, you can test it with regex

Comment: There is no need to test against a regular expression. `.wrap-3-addon-1` are already selected (alone).

Answer (score 2):

Inspiring regex matching from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246601/wildcard-string-comparison-in-javascript):

```js
var $ele = $("div:first");

alert(matchRule($ele.attr('class'),'wrap-*-addon-1'))


function matchRule(str, rule) {
  return new RegExp("^" + rule.split("*").join(".*") + "$").test(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap-1-addon-1">
</div>
<div class="wrap-2-addon-1">
</div>
<div class="wrap-3-addon-1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you, i used regex to resolve if current element's class(es) suits the desired pattern.

I assume you have more than 3 classes to check. 
This pattern is for wrap-1-addon-1 to wrap-n-addon-1, n is some digit

```js
function hasMyClass(elm) {
  
var regex = /(wrap-)+(\d)+(-addon-1)/i;// this is the regex pattenr for wrap-*-addon-1
  
var $this = $(elm);
var myClassesStr = $this.attr('class');
if(myClassesStr) { // if this has any class
  var myClasses = myClassesStr.split(' '); // split the classes
  for(i=0;i<myClasses.length;i++) { // foreach class
      var myClass = myClasses[i]; // take one of classes
      var found = myClass.match(regex); // check if regex matches the class
    
      if(found) {
          return true;
        }
    }
}
  
return false;
}



function test() {
    $('#container div').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $('#pTest').append('<br/>test result for ' + $this.attr('id') + ':' + hasMyClass(this)); 
      // hasMyClass(this) is the sample usage
    })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1" class="wrap-1-addon-1 anotherClass">div1 (wrap-1-addon-1)</div>
  <div id="div2"  class="wrap-2-addon-1 anotherClass anotherClass2">div2 (wrap-2-addon-1)</div>
  <div id="div3"  class="wrap-3-addon-1 anotherClass">div3 (wrap-3-addon-1)</div>
  <div id="div4"  class="anotherClass">div4 (none)</div>
</div>
<button id="testBtn" onclick="test();" type="button">TEST</button>

<p id="pTest" >...</p>
```