# How to match string with a wildcard in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, routes, wildcard

I am trying to write a function that checks if a route is included in an array of routes:

```
const routes = ['/test', '/documentation/*']

function checkRoute(route) {
  if (routes.includes(route)) {
    console.log('Included!!')
  } else { 
    console.log('Not included!')
  }
}
```

The part I need help with is how to handle the wildcard `*` - basically, I want any route that has the `/docs/` prefix to be included such as:

`/documentation/docs.json`, `/documentation/index.html`

Besides doing some very messy string manipulation, I am not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex.

```js
const routes = ['\\/test\\/*', '\\/documentation\\/*']

function checkRoute(route) {
  let regex = new RegExp(route);
  let matchedRoutes = routes.filter(route => regex.test(route))
}
```

Comment: John should change `'/documentation/*'` to `'/documentation/.*'` since it's regex, not wildcard matching. Or perhaps `'^/documentation/.*'` so it only matches from the root of the route.

Comment: @Chris `.*` isn't needed at the end, unless you anchor it with `$`.

Comment: @Chris I guess it should be changed to `\\/documentation\\/*` for the regex to be properly created with RegExp.
`new RegExp('\\/documentation\\/*')` returns `/\/documentation\/*/`

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to do this that uses my original `routes` array `const routes = ['/test', '/documentation/*']` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple form of wildcard match function. It is not a bad idea to use it and support all types of wildcard comparrsion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32402438/635891