# How do you repeat a pattern and extract the contents in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do something fairly simple however I have not worked extensively with Regex before.

I am trying to extract some strings out of another string.

I have the string 'value/:id/:foo/:bar'

I would like to extract each string after the colon and before slash eg:

```
let s = 'value/:id/:foo/:bar';
let r = new RegExp(/MAGIC HERE/);
// result r.exec(s)
```

I have been trying for an hour or so on this website: https://regex101.com/ but can only get as close as this:

```
:([a-z]+)
```

I also tried playing with these examples but couldn't get anywhere:

[Regex match everything after question mark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419000/regex-match-everything-after-question-mark)

[How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression/14210948)

I want to be able to extract these parameters infinitely if possible.

My intended result is to get an array of each of the parameters.

```
group 1 - id
group 2 - foo
group 3 - bar
```

Please consider explaining the regex that can help with this I want to understand how groups are formed in the regex.

Comment: `'value/:id/:foo/:bar'.match(/:[a-z]+/g)` is this what you're after?

Comment: @Isaac Yes! Thanks for the hint. I should have been testing my string against the regex not the other way around!

Comment: Yea that'd do it. Should be fairly simple to extend to using numbers, capitals, underscores, etc. Sometimes it just takes a fresh mind to look at the problem eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'value/:id/:foo/:bar'.match(/:[a-z]+/g)
```

Returns

```
[":id", ":foo", ":bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
 let reg=/:(.*?)\/|:(.*?)$/g;
 let reg2=/:(.*?)\/|:(.*?)$/;
 let str='value/:id/:foo/:bar';
 let result=str.match(reg).map(v=>v.match(reg2)[1]?v.match(reg2)[1]:v.match(reg2)[2]);

 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

"/:"
This regex , don't try to match the text between separators, but the separator '/:'.

I hope this help...

```js
let s = 'value/:id/:foo/:bar';
s = s.split("\/\:").splice(1).map((current, index) => `group ${index+1}: - ${current}`);
console.log(s);
```